# PHP form validation: Regular expressions issues

Tags: php, validation

I have simple php validation form that is halfway working. If you leave the field empty and click submit, it does the display the correct error message. The issue is with the regular expressions. For example if the currency field is not valid it doesnt display the correct error message. As a matter when clicking submit it reloads the page and erases all the values in the textboxes. How come it will not display the correct error message?

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">

                <label for="tile">Title: <em>*</em></label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $form['title']; ?>"> <?php echo $error['title'] ?>


                <label for="currency">Currency: <em>*</em></label>
                <input type="text" name="currency" id="currency" value="<?php echo $form['currency']; ?>"> <?php echo $error['currency'] ?>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

        </form>
```

**PHP Validator**

```
  //variables
    $error_open = "<label class='error'>";
    $error_close = "</label>";
    $valid_form = TRUE;
    $redirect = "success.php";

    $form_elements = array('title', 'currency');
    $required = array('title', 'currency');

    foreach ($required as $require)
    {
        $error[$require] = '';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //process form

        //get form data
        foreach ($form_elements as $element)
        {
            $form[$element] = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$element]);
        }

        //check form elements
            //check required fields
            if ($form['title'] == '')
            {
                $error['title'] =  $error_open . "* This field is required" . $error_close;
                $valid_form = FALSE;
            }
            if ($form['currency'] == '')
            {
                $error['currency'] = $error_open . "* This field is required" . $error_close;
                $valid_form = FALSE;
            }


            //check formatting
            if ($error['title'] == '' && !preg_match('/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/', $form['title']))
            {

                $error['title'] = $error_open . "* Enter a valid descriptive title" . $error_close;
                $valid_form = FALSE;

            }

            if ($error['currency'] == '' && !preg_match('/^\s*[+-]?(\d*\.\d\d)\s*$/', $form['currency']))
            {

                $error['currency'] = $error_open . " Enter a valid decimal number <br> * Do not include Dollar($) sign <br> * Example: (1.00)" . $error_close;
                $valid_form = FALSE;

            }



        //check for bad data
            if (contains_bad_str($form['title']) ||
            contains_bad_str($form['currency']))
            {
                $valid_form = FALSE;

            }

            if (contains_bad_str($form['title']) ||
            contains_bad_str($form['currency']))
            {
                $valid_form = FALSE;

            }

        //check if form is valid
        if ($valid_form)
        {

            //redirect
            header("Location: " . $redirect);

        }
        else
        {
            include('form.php');

        }

    }
```

Comment: Something wrong with `is_numeric()`?

Comment: You can also help yourself by trimming the inputs, then you don't need the check for spaces in the preg__match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me.

```
function contains_bad_str($s) {
    $r = preg_match ( "/cheese|rice|beans/i" , $s);
    return $r;
}

// variables
$error_open = "<label class='error'>";
$error_close = "</label>";
$valid_form = TRUE;
$redirect = "success.php";

$form_elements = array('title', 'currency');
$metadata = array('title'=> array('/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/',
                                  "* Enter a valid descriptive title"),
                  'currency' => array('/^\s*[+-]?(\d*\.\d\d)\s*$/',
                                      "* Enter a valid decimal number <br/>" .
                                      "* Do not include Dollar($) sign <br/>" .
                                      "* Example: (1.00)" ));

foreach ($form_elements as $element) {
    $error[$element] = '';
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // get form data
    foreach ($form_elements as $element) {
        $form[$element] = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$element]);
        // check presence
        if ($form[$element] == '') {
            $error[$element] =  $error_open . "* required" . $error_close;
            $valid_form = FALSE;
        }
        // check formatting
        elseif (!preg_match($metadata[$element][0], $form[$element])) {
            $error[$element] = $error_open . $metadata[$element][1] . $error_close;
            $valid_form = FALSE;
        }
        // sanitize
        elseif (contains_bad_str($form[$element])) {
            $error[$element] =  $error_open . "* bad string" . $error_close;
            $valid_form = FALSE;
        }
    }

    if ($valid_form) {
        header("Location: " . $redirect);
    }
    else {
        include('form.php');
    }
}
else {
    // blank form
    $form = array('title'=>'', 'currency'=>'');
    $error = array('title'=>'', 'currency'=>'');
    include('form.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [PHP's input filters](http://www.php.net/filter)? In particular, have a look at [`FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) for currency.